# Signing an iOS framework plugin for Unity and including it in my Unity app for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, plugins, apple-developer

I'm trying to build a Unity app for iOS.

For this app, I'm building a Framework Project in XCode that I will be using as a plugin library. I've successfully imported the plugin as a .framework folder and embedded it as a binary.

However, when I now build the app and deploy it to my iPhone for testing I get the error message "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified", so it seems like the signing of the plugin is not correct. If I remove it again, the app works fine.

I tried:

1. ...creating a new bundle identifier and a provisioning profile for it and signed it with the bundle identifier. Didn't help.
2. ...signing it with the same identifier as the Unity App. Now the error message just changed to "can't be installed. Try again later"

I read that if it's flagged as a developer build I would need to accept a certificate in the devices screen on the iPhone, but no new certificates are showing up there.

Any thoughts on how to proceed with this? I'm new to Swift development, so I might have missed something simple. I'm using MacInCloud for XCode development, then moving the plugin to my PC, and building and deploying the final app with iOS Project Builder for Unity (which is an amazing plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my situation. I reset all my certificates and started from scratch. I made sure to only create one private key which I then exported to all my other environments so that every part of the project uses the same private key. This solved the issue.